# compare values of two column on two difference pandas data frame and return max

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have data frame df1:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'id': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'B'}, 'col1': {0: '7', 1: ' ', 2: '8', 3: '3', 4: '5', 5: '1'}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

and df2 :

```
data2 = {'id': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'testCol': {0: '0', 1: '4', 2: '1'}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

by using pandas or numpy, How can compare df1['col1'] and df2['testCol'] for each id, and return max value in df2['testCol'] or in new column in df2?

result:

| ID | testCol |
| --- | --- |
| A | 8 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 5 |

OR

| ID | testCol | maxCol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 8 |
| B | 4 | 4 |
| C | 1 | 5 |

-df1 and df2 are examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = (
    pd.concat(
        [df1.groupby("id")["col1"].max(), df2.set_index("id")["testCol"]],
        axis=1,
    )
    .max(axis=1)
    .astype(int)
    .reset_index(name="testCol")
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  id  testCol
0  A        8
1  B        4
2  C        5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is this:

```py
result = (
    df1.set_index('id')
    .merge(df2.set_index('id'), on='id')
    .max(axis=1)
)
```

which gives:

```sh
id
A    7.0
A    0.0
A    8.0
B    4.0
B    4.0
C    5.0
dtype: float64
```

then you can groupby `id` and get the overall max:

```py
result = (
    df1.set_index('id')
    .merge(df2.set_index('id'), on='id')
    .max(axis=1)
    .groupby('id')
    .max()
)
```

output:

```sh
id
A    8.0
B    4.0
C    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thank you. Is merge() more efficient than concat()?

Comment: it depends... sometimes yes. Have a look at pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#merge-join-concatenate-and-compare

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in just a couple steps:

- Rename "col1" to "testCol" to ensure everything aligns correctly
- Vertically stack df1 and df2
- Group by ID, and get the maximum of "testCol"

```
out = (
    df1.rename(columns={"col1": "testCol"})
    .append(df2)
    .groupby("id", as_index=False)
    ["testCol"].max()
)

print(out)
  id testCol
0  A       8
1  B       4
2  C       5
```